# MS access query aggregation

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get query  like this

```
SELECT sales.action_date, sales.item_id, items.item_name, 
       sales.item_quantity, sales.item_price, sales.net 
FROM sales INNER JOIN items ON sales.item_id = items.ID 
GROUP BY sales.item_id 
HAVING (((sales.action_date)=[Forms]![rep_frm]![Text13].[value]));
```

Every time I try to show data this message show

> your query does not include the specified expression ' action date '
>   as part of aggregate function.

and for all field in the query >>> but i just want the aggregation be for item_id

what i should do?

Comment: If you are including other fields in the SELECT statement all the fields need to have some sort of aggregation on them. The default being GROUP BY. If you edit your post with some example and result data; maybe we could help you better !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any aggregations like SUM in your SELECT statement. I also don't understand why you sales.action_date is in de HAVING clause. This is for aggregated filtering like SUM(sales.item_price) <> 0. It should be possible to put this part in de WHERE-clause, before the GROUP BY instead of the HAVING clause.
This example should work:

```
SELECT sales.item_id, items.item_name, SUM(sales.item_quantity), 
       SUM(sales.item_price), SUM(sales.net) 
FROM sales INNER JOIN items ON sales.item_id = items.ID 
WHERE sales.action_date=[Forms]![rep_frm]![Text13].[value] 
GROUP BY sales.item_id, items.item_name;
```

Comment: thaaanx iam not notice that sales.action_date in the field thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When you are grouping your data all fields in select query should be either included in `group by` clause, or some aggregate function should be applied to it - otherwise it doesn't makee sense.

By the way - as far as I can see, you should use `WHERE(((sales.action_date)=[Forms]![rep_frm]![Text13].[value]))` before group, not `HAVING` after.

Comment: but in this way no aggregation happen!

Comment: If IDs are unique, grouping by ID won't aggregate anything. If you want sales by date, GROUP BY should contain only the date and select should contain the date and sums for the amount fields you want to aggregate.

Comment: could you please write it to me??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to aggregate by date you have to put the date in the `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT sales.action_date, 
       SUM(sales.item_quantity), 
       SUM(sales.item_quantity * sales.item_price) as Total, 
       SUM(sales.net)
FROM sales 
     INNER JOIN items ON sales.item_id = items.ID 
WHERE (((sales.action_date)=[Forms]![rep_frm]![Text13].[value]));
GROUP BY sales.action_date
```

Only the column you want to group by can appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Only these columns can appear in the select clause outside of aggregation functions.