# Group [Col-OFF] with duplicate or identical values (Short text), and [Col-Amt $$] I want to group dups from [Col-OFF] and Sum of dups in column

Tags: ms-access, vba6

I have a table named tbl-Rec with columns [*Col-OFFICE*] that contains duplicate or identical values, and [*Col-Amt*] that has the corresponding dollar values of Col-Office. I need to show in a query result the total amount of all identical duplicates in a row. Sample table:

******Tbl_Rec******

| **Col-Office** | **Col-Amt** |
| --- | --- |
| 123-1260-14000-ANC0523 | $45.00 |
| 123-1260-14000-BNK0422 | $68.00 |
| 123-1260-14000-ANC0523 | $38.00 |
| 123-1260-14000-ANC0523 | $42.00 |
| 123-1260-14000-ANC0523 | $18.00 |
| 123-1260-14000-BNK0422 | $89.00 |

The column [Col-Office] has six rows of two sets of duplicates, thereby expecting two rows of expected results below.

**Expected Result:**

| **Col-Office** | **Col-Amt** |
| --- | --- |
| 123-1260-14000-ANC0523 | $143.00 |
| 123-1260-14000-BNK0422 | $157.00 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Build an aggregate query: `SELECT [Col-Office], Sum([Col-Amt]) AS SumAmt FROM [Tbl-Rec] GROUP BY [Col-Office];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS access query aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300472/ms-access-query-aggregation)

Comment: the query designer is very helpful for group queries: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WECG3TXxgk